# Does a SQL Server Cursor Process Rows From a Temp Table In Order or Randomly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

A #tempTable is

- created and used in a stored procedure (`dbo.deleteStuff`)
- populated with rows to be processed by a cursor in that same stored proc

Does the cursor process the rows of the temp table in order those rows were loaded to the temp table, or randomly/non-deterministically? BOL doesn't specifically answer this question (the closest I saw was `KEYSET`), and I've not seen blog posts/etc that directly answer or hint at how the engine parses this particular scenario.

There are only three columns for the temp table being loaded and processed:

- A human-readable summary of why something is being deleted
  (effectively logged to `dbo.tblWhatGotDeleted`).
- The unique identifier of the row getting deleted (same).
- SQL that has been dynamically generated and stored in this temp
  table, and this code is what ultimately gets executed by the cursor.

Other facts:

- The delete statements are dynamically generated by comparing a source
  view to a destination table (e.g. compare `tblFoo EXCEPT vwFoo`.) If rows no
  longer exist in the source view that are in the target table, the
  rows in the target table are slated for deletion and written to the
  temp table. The proc repeats this process for roughly two dozen tables.
- The proc generates these statements in an order that writes rows for
  foreign keyed tables first, then writes primary key rows for related
  tables to delete. This proc has worked this way for some time,
  deleting rows for all foreign-keyed rows seemingly first, then
  deleting rows for primary keys so no constraints are theoretically enforced or
  tripped over.
- There is not an INT / Identity / Primary Key / Index on the temp table
- In spite of a unique identifier / value  getting stored in the temp
  table, no order is enforced by the cursor (that I'm aware of) due to
  the temp table holding delete statements for many, many tables, not
  just one (see below)
- All processing that loads the temp table is done in one batch. At the
  end of the load, the cursor is called and executes the SQL to start
  culling rows out of tables.
- Yes, it's ugly. :)

Temp table load order, driven by dynamic SQL:

```
DELETE from tblFoo where thisidentifer = '1';
DELETE from tblFoo where thisidentifier = '5';
DELETE from tblFoo where thisidentifier = '7';
DELETE from tblBar where thatidentifier = 'Apple';
DELETE from tblBar where thatidentifier = 'Orange';
DELETE from tblBar where thatIdentifier = 'Pear';
DELETE from tblBlargh where otheridentifier = 'Alpha';
DELETE from tblBlargh where otheridentifier = 'Beta';
DELETE from tblBlargh where otheridentifier = 'Gamma';
```

Can I count on the cursor to process these statements in the same order?

```
 DELETE from tblFoo where thisidentifer = '1';
 DELETE from tblFoo where thisidentifier = '5';
 DELETE from tblFoo where thisidentifier = '7';
 DELETE from tblBar where thatidentifier = 'Apple';
 DELETE from tblBar where thatidentifier = 'Orange';
 DELETE from tblBar where thatIdentifier = 'Pear';
 DELETE from tblBlargh where otheridentifier = 'Alpha';
 DELETE from tblBlargh where otheridentifier = 'Beta';
 DELETE from tblBlargh where otheridentifier = 'Gamma';
```

Past behavior of this proc would *imply* that the rows are processed in the order of INSERT, but I may just have not gotten burned by the engine yet.

Here's the cursor code:

```
    DECLARE deleteRows CURSOR FOR
select deleteList.* from #stuffToDelete as deleteList

OPEN deleteRows

    FETCH next FROM deleteRows INTO @summaryOfWhatsGettingNuked, @theIdentifierForWhatsGettingNuked, @theSqlThatDoesTheNuking

WHILE (@@Fetch_Status = 0)
 BEGIN

    EXEC (@theSqlThatDoesTheNuking)

    FETCH next FROM deleteRows INTO @summaryOfWhatsGettingNuked, @theIdentifierForWhatsGettingNuked, @theSqlThatDoesTheNuking

 END

CLOSE deleteRows
DEALLOCATE deleteRows
```

Comment: The answer is, is that the order is arbitrary if you don't have an ORDER BY clause in your SQL statement. If could be the same order, it could be totally different. Add an IDENTITY column to the temporary table, order by that IDENTITY and you'll be good.

Comment: I mean add that order by clause to the select-part of the cursor definition.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!